# Get the column index with the current date

Tags: calendar, match

I have a google sheet with columns set up as dates.
So, A2=1/1/2021, A3 = 1/2/2021, A4 = 1/3/2021 and so on. This is (m/d/yyyy)

This is how it looks like:

[Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqYBr.png)

I wish to do a lookup to find the date matching it with my calendar event.

I extract my calendar event with below.

```
var id_cal = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
var cal= CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id_cal);
var start_time = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
var end_time  = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(start_time), new Date(end_time))
for(var i = 0;i<events.length;i++){
  var start_time = events[i].getStartTime();
  ...
}
```

*EDIT:

1. The script pulls calendar events from G.Cal.
2. The event title need to be placed in the second row in the google sheet (see image)
3. So if the calendar event starts on 3rd Jan, it will be placed below the cell that shows '3' in the image.

So,

```
var detail = events[i].getTitle();
sheet.getRange(row=2,column= X ) = "My event : " + detail ;
```

I need to find 'X', based on the date in start_time().*

Without app script, match function works best. but it doesn't work in app script. I would really like to avoid 365 iterations of the for loop for every event. It would be nice if there was a way to use match() or hlookup(), within the appscript.

EDIT2: This is how the image must look like:
[Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPmRg.png)
How do I fill the events in Row 2 from my google calendar. So that they appear below the cell with correct date.
Example: There is a meeting with A on 1/1/2022.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I wish to compare the date in start_time variable with the column values; and update a row in the same column where date(start_time) = date(displayed in the columns). To do this, I need the column index that has the same date. Any suggestions on how do i find it.`. And, I cannot understand the relationship between your script and your sample image. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: hi, thank you for checking this. I edited the question, is it better now ? Let me know if i can clarify this further ?

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. I could understand the section 1 in your added "*EDIT:". But I couldn't understand 2 to 4 sections in your added "*EDIT:". But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you for reviewing it. I have changed the points in 2 and 4. I also added EDIT2: Can you look at the target sheet ? This will help you know what i want to do. Please let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Any idea @Tanaike